# What are some of the mantras which give success in examinations?

Tags: mantras

What are the mantras to be recited to gain success in examinations as per scriptures?

Comment: Hello! .. after a long gap :)

Comment: Ram naam @Sethu

Comment: Hope you are doing great Rickross Ji @Rickross

Comment: Yes thanks @SethuSrivatsaKoduru